# mongodb find array of object and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this format in my db

```
[{
  "birth-date": "18/12/2010",
  "babies": [{
    "id":1,
    "name": "James",
    "age": 8,
  }, {
    "id":2,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 4,
  }]
}]
```

so I want to update James's name to something else. I do

```
Babies.update({"birth-date":date, 'babies.id': 1}, {'$set': {'babies.$.name':"something else"}}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })
```

It returned `ok:0` something is wrong with the second selector `('babies.id': 1)`.

Comment: I don't know mongoose, but in mongo shell `Babies.update({"birth-date", 'babies.id': 1},...`will give an error because `"birth-date"` needs :something, that is the property needs a key (for instance  `Babies.update({"birth-date":"18/12/2010", 'babies.id': 1},...`

Comment: @RafaelCaballero updated my answer, it was just typo.

Comment: Can you try replacing the set part with '$set': {'babies.$.name':"something else"} ?

Comment: @SagarReddy tried, nope.

Comment: Are you missing the closing curly for set ?

Comment: @SagarReddy updated my question. It's a typo.

Comment: Have you tried the same in mongo shell ? May it's just mongoose syntax

Comment: @SagarReddy I tried `Babies.update({'babies.id': 1}, {'$set': {'babies.$.name':"something else"}}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })` it doesn't work too, does it have to do with my schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$and` selector for this call;

```
Babies.update({
      $and: [{
        'birth-date': date
      },
      {
        'babies': {
          $elemMatch: {
            'id': id_you_are_searching
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    },
      {$set: {'babies.$.name':"something else"}}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

To match documents based on some array property, you need **$elemMatch**

```
Babies
  .update({ babies: {$elemMatch:{id : 1}} }, {'$set': {name:"something else"}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })
```

Check this out : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: this is just single condition. I need date and baby id.

Comment: You can easily add any number of conditions, just like any other query.

Babies
  .update({ babies: {$elemMatch:{id : 1}},  'birth-date': "18/12/2010"}, {'$set': {name:"something else"}, function(err, response){
        res.json(response);
  })

Comment: $elemMatch is not needed here. It is used when you need several conditions. If you need just equality, as in your case, `'babies.id':1` is perfect, In fact, I have tried in mongo `db.collection.update({"birth-date":"18/12/2010", "babies.id":1}, {'$set':{name:'something'}})` and it works fine, with`collection` containing  your document.

Comment: @RafaelCaballero the problem is I failed to select the correct target.